# Recibir respuesta SalesForce Token ID desde Navision

Tags: webservice, oauth2

Estoy intentando montar una llamada al servicio de SalesForce para obtener un token id y poder utilizarlo en demás llamadas.
El código del lado de NAV2016 es el siguiente:

```
zRExternalCRMSetup.TESTFIELD("URL Token");
  zRExternalCRMSetup.TESTFIELD(User);
  zRExternalCRMSetup.TESTFIELD(Password);
  zRExternalCRMSetup.TESTFIELD("Consumer Key");
  zRExternalCRMSetup.TESTFIELD("Consumer Secret");
  zRExternalCRMSetup.TESTFIELD("Security Token");

  xTextPasswordToken := zRExternalCRMSetup.Password+zRExternalCRMSetup."Security Token";
  
  HttpWebRequestMgt.Initialize(zRExternalCRMSetup."URL Token");
  HttpWebRequestMgt.DisableUI();
  HttpWebRequestMgt.kAddSecurityProtocolTls12();
  HttpWebRequestMgt.SetMethod('POST');
  HttpWebRequestMgt.SetContentType('application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');

  xChar13 := 13;
  xChar10 := 10;
  HttpWebRequestMgt.AddBodyAsText('grant_type=password' + FORMAT(xChar13) + FORMAT(xChar10) + '&client_id='+ UrlEncode(zRExternalCRMSetup."Consumer Key") + FORMAT(xChar13) + FORMAT(xChar10) + 
  '&client_secret=' + UrlEncode(zRExternalCRMSetup."Consumer Secret") + FORMAT(xChar13) + FORMAT(xChar10) + '&username=' + UrlEncode(zRExternalCRMSetup.User) + FORMAT(xChar13) + FORMAT(xChar10) + '&password='+UrlEncode(xTextPasswordToken));
  
  TempBlob.INIT;
  TempBlob.Blob.CREATEINSTREAM(InStr);

  IF HttpWebRequestMgt.GetResponse(InStr, HttpStatusCode, ResponseHeaders) THEN BEGIN
    xResponseJson := TempBlob.ReadAsText('', TEXTENCODING::UTF8);
    xJSONMng.InitializeObject(xResponseJson);
    xTokenIDSalesForce := xJSONMng.GetValue('access_token');
    EXIT(xTokenIDSalesForce);
  END ELSE
    HttpWebRequestMgt.ProcessFaultResponse('');
```

Siempre recibo un Error 400 del lado del servidor. La cuestión es que la misma llamada desde Postman funciona perfectamente, con los mismos headers y el mismo body.

No sé donde puede estar fallando el código.